# Start and stop loop counter javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this counter:

http://jsfiddle.net/nsu77w92/17/

It's principle is to count down, run some function and then count down again.

The function is being runned like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
countdown();
},10000);
```

I can't figure it out, how to make start and stop for it.

I have tried something like this:

```
function start() {
    timer = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
};

function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
```

but it doesn't work. Could someone help me with that? Do you have any suggestions to resolve it? Please check the fiddle (link above)

Comment: When is the `stop()` called? Where is `tick` function.

Comment: This is what I have tried, I have applied to the code, but this example copied here is copied from another source.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return and assign to variable *timerId* from `start function` and pass that variable as argument into `stop function` call, as in code snippet below:

```
function start() {
    var tick = function(){
        console.log('I am tick function');
    };
    var timerId = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    return timerId
};
var timerId = start();
function stop(timerId) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
};
stop(timerId);
```

Regarding your code snippet provided in comments, i've updated it [to that one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVbBEv).

Pay attention to modification of interaction with *timerId* variable. The problem was in the way  you are tracked it ( *timerId*). When you call `setTimeout` function within `tick function` you have to refresh value of "new ticker", in that way you would be able to stop latest function which is passed into `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please check my fiddle and see what function I am using. This code seems doesn't work like I need :( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obJMJO

Comment: Thanks I see it. It would be perfect, but start now works only for first loop. I need it to work as on my first post fiddle. It loops everytime. After finishing counting it runs function and starts again automatically.

Comment: Whatever I have fixed it and found a way out. However, your answer helped me a lot. Thank you again!

Comment: @Simon You are welcome, it was nice to assist you! Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.

If someone would need it, here you go:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obJMJO

```
function start(){
countdown();
}
function stop(){
clearTimeout(timerI)
}
sectotal = 5;
function countdown() {
        var secs = sectotal;

        function timer() {
            secs--;
         $("#counter").html("(" + secs + ")")


            if( secs > 0 ) {
                timerI = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
            } else {
                alert('repeat!')
                secs = sectotal
                countdown();
            }
        }
        timer();
}
```

And html:

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<button onclick="start()">
Start
</button>
<button onclick="stop()">
Stop
</button>
```